# Join and Dynamic `Where` in Laravel4 Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm building a search form which needs to perform a search in 3 main tables:
users, users_info and users_data

The thing is that I dont know how much filters i'm getting from the query, is there a way to loop while querying and set the `where`? something like:

```
return User::join('personal_info','users.id','=','personal_info.user_id')
    ->leftJoin('user_data','users.id','=','user_data.user_id', function($q){
        foreach ( $filters as $field => $value ) {
            $q->where($field,'=',$value)
        }
    })
->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it, I can assign the joins into a variable and then loop and add conditions:

```
$query = Model::join('users_data','user.id','=','users_data.id');
foreach ( $conditions as $cond ) {
 $query->where('...');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's true.

And also if you don't have a initial method to initialize the Eloquent Model to assign it to a variable like:

```
$query = Model::join('users_data','user.id','=','users_data.id');
```

You can instantiate it using the **new** keyword, like below:

```
$query = new Model;
```

And then loop and add the **where** statements dynamically.

Here's an example:

```
        $items = new Model;

        if ( Input::has('param1') )
            $items = $items->where('param1_id', '=', Input::get('param1'));
        if ( Input::has('param2') )
            $items = $items->where('param2_id', '=', Input::get('param2'));
        if ( Input::has('param3') )
            $items = $items->where('param3_id', '=', Input::get('param3'));
        if ( Input::has('param4') )
            $items = $items->where('param4_id', '=', Input::get('param4'));

        $items = $items->get();
```

I found part of the solution in the Laravel Community: http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=2985